# Execute command on remote windows machine and get output in python

Tags: python, windows, authentication, execute

I want to write a script that executes command on remote windows machine, and get output from that command. The problem is, I want to use built-in software in windows, so I can't unfortunately use for example SSH for that. I found "wmi" library, and I can log in to the machine and execute command, but i don't know how to recieve output from that command.

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI("10.0.0.2", user="administrator", password="admin")
process_startup = c.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
process_id, result = c.Win32_Process.Create (r'cmd /c ping 10.0.0.1 -n 1 > c:\temp\temp.txt')
if result == 0:
  print("Process started successfully: %d" % process_id)

print(result)
```

I tried to redirect output to file, but I can't find any way to get text file content either.

Is there any possible way to get output or text file content using wmi, or other python libraries?

Answer (score 0):

For the application you're describing you may find [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good fit.  It's a python remoting server you can connect to and issue commands; it will do anything that Python can do on the target machine. So you could, for example, use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to run a windows command and capture the output then return the result.

The safe thing to do is to expose your remote functionality as a service -- basically, it's just a python script that RPyC can run for you.  However you can also use RPyC [classic mode](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/classic.html#classic), which is pretty much like running a python session directly on the remote machine.  You should use it only when you are not worried about security, since classic mode can do *anything* on the remote machine -- but it's useful for prototyping.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it should work well in my case. I have a lot of windows machines, that's why I tried to solve this case using built-in solutions, where additional configuration is unnecessary. If I won't find any way to do it with wmi, then I'll probably use this solution :)